# How to find pros to take on maintenance/improvement of pre-existing sites built with Craft?

Tags: resources

I know of the [Craft Professionals](https://straightupcraft.com/professionals) page on Straight Up Craft, but I'm curious if there is a more targeted way to find Craft pros who are willing and able to take on maintenance of pre-existing Craft sites.

This Q/A site seems obviously wrong for that. Are there other places to post requests or find a list of potential partners?

I hope this question is considered on-topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this posting, there isn't another *reliable* source for Craft professionals. The CMS is so new compared to other systems that a 'base' of well-known, reliable companies/developers hasn't had the chance to form yet.

You could google and find a few, but they're spread out among developers that most likely wouldn't give you good results. I'd stick with the Straight Up Craft list, since you're at least sure they've seen/read about best practices on the Straight Up Craft site.

You could also post jobs to places like [Authentic Jobs](https://authenticjobs.com/), and specifically ask for Craft experience, or Straight Up Craft's [Job Board](https://straightupcraft.com/jobs).

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the community page on the [craft website](http://buildwithcraft.com/community) and get in touch with people in the meet ups, if they are local.

Or alternatively and more specifically, you could always join Craft on slack (get access from the community page) and from there you can easily engage with Craft enthusiasts and there is also a specific jobs channel you can post any jobs or work placements etc you might have to find partnerships and just generally meet new crafters :)